# Getting BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language

Tags: asp.net, exception, web-deployment, asp.net-core-2.0, badimageformatexception

I am trying to deploy my app on a host, and first it worked perfectly.

But then I get back to my code made some changes there (javascript only) and when i try to publish again it shows me this error.

`BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.`

[image]

Can someone please help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the .net framework version targeting the wrong processor architecture, Make sure the version you are compiling your application in is set to "Any CPU" or matches the CPU architecture of your web host.

Comment: Its already set to Any CPU. But what really confuzes me is that, the first time it worked perfectly, and then in the second publish stopped working

Comment: You may want to check your build configurations, make sure they are all set to the same CPU. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa.aspx.